# Guardar datos de un .txt

Tags: python, matrices

Buenas a todos tengo una duda de cómo guardar los datos de un `.txt` que están de tal forma:

Datos 1

```
1.0  2.0
1.0  3.0
2.0  3.0
```

Elementos 1

```
3.0 32.0
4.1 54. 6
```

Datos 2

```
2.2 1.0
23.0 9.0
32.0 2.0
```

Ir guardándolos en diferentes matrices nombrando a estas con el nombre que tienen para que queden tal que así:

```
Datos1=[[1.0,2.0][1.0,3.0][2.0,3.0]]...
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Antonio. Mírate [ask] y [tour] para conocer como realizar buenas preguntas y conocer el funcionamiento general del sitio. Deberias agregar que has intentado hacer hasta el moemnto. Crear variables de forma dinámica es posible usando eval pero es muy peligroso y mala práctica. Replantearte usar otro contenedor, por ejemplo un diccionario: `Datos = {"Datos1":[[1.0,2.0], [1.0,3.0], [2.0,3.0]], "Datos2" [[2.2,  1.0], [23.0, 9.0], [32.0, 2.0]]}`. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer algo como:

```
file = open('your_file.txt', 'r')
read_file = file.readlines()
file.close()

a = []

for i in range(len(read_file)):
    a.append(read_file[i].rstrip().split('  '))

print(a)
```

Aca lo primero que hacemos es abrir el archivo, luego leemos las lineas y lo cerramos, despues creamos una lista vacia. El ciclo lo que hace es leer cuantas filas tiene el archivo, luego agregamos esa linea a la lista `a` y con `rstrip` eliminamos el salto de linea, con `split` eliminamos los 2 espacios que tiene entre los 2 numerous, segun tu ejemplo tiene 2 espacios, pero el segundo ejemplo tiene solo uno.

Ya queda en tus manos como organizar el resto, pero es el mismo codigo

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes mi solución a tu problema. Te recomiendo que no intentes hacer variable el nombre de una variable ya es el inestable y se te puede complicar.

```
# Recuperar datos de archivo
def openFile(ruta):
   data = open(ruta,"r")
   return data

# Guardar datos en una matriz
def formatData(data):
   matrix = []
   for line in data:
      matrix.append([float(x) for x in line.strip().split(" ")])
   return matrix

# ===================
# Algoritmo principal
def main():
   ruta = "Datos1.txt";
   data = openFile(ruta)
   matrix = formatData(data)

# Tu programa empieza aquí
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos